# How can I push a div inside the profoundgrid "responsive fluid" style to the right?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout, profound-grid

I'm using the profound grid framework to build responsive fluid grid layout. Basically what I want to achieve is to create a layout containing 6 colums of which the menu container is on the left with 1 column width and the content is on the right with 5 columns width. Inside the content I have a nested grid that is also fluid.

I have the grid working as the responsive fluid example which can be found here: http://www.profoundgrid.com/examples/fluidresponsive.html

The scss code I have looks like this:

```
#row{
    div{@include column(6);}
    .col1{@include column(2);}
    .col5{@include column(10);}
    @include generate_grid_positions(div, 1);
}
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<article id="row">
        <div id="menuContainer" class="col1">Menu <br />menu <br />menu</div>
        <div id="contentContainer" class="col5">
            <div id="projectContainer">
                <div class="project">project1</div>
                <div class="project">project2</div>
                <div class="project">project3</div>
                <div class="project">project1</div>
                <div class="project">project2</div>
                <div class="project">project3</div>
            </div>
            <div id="socialContainer">sadfgsdfg</div>
        </div>
    </article>
```

What I have right now is a fluid responsive grid, but both divs get stacked upon eachother. I would like to know how to push the content 2 columns to the right.

Comment: And the question is ? How can i make a div ? Where is your html ?

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it was vague. I updated the question

Comment: @include generate_grid_positions(div, 2); seems to push it just right, though it is only a solution for this case. I still don't understand how I should use it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
<article class="grid1">
    <div class="col2 push0">menu</div>
    <div class="col2 push2">c1</div>
    <div class="col2 push4">c2</div>
    <div class="col2 push6">c3</div>
    <div class="col2 push8">c4</div>
    <div class="col2 push10">c5</div>
</article>
```

merge the 5 right columns :

```
<article class="grid1">
    <div class="col2 push0">menu</div>
    <div class="col10 push2">5 times width</div>
</article>
```

And to make sure you learn not much (becoz it's copy pasted from your OP link), YOUR solution is :

```
<article>
    <div class="col3">left</div>
    <div class="col9 push3">right</div>
</article>
```

Comment: This works for the fixed grid but not for the fluid responsive.